# Django - How to track user progress across multiple days?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, chart.js

I have a django model that updates with the user's current time spent on the website:

```
totallearningtime = models.DecimalField(default = 0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=100) # total time user spent on website
```

And I have the following **chart.js** that I want to populate with the *totallearningtime* through the week, and reset at the begining of the next week:

[image]

(right now it has placeholder values)

Here is the code for the chart:

```
<script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

            // <block:setup:1>
            const DATA_COUNT = 12;
            const labels = [
                "Mon",
                "Tue",
                "Wen",
                "Thur",
                "Fri",
                "Sat",
                "Sun",
               
            ];
            
            const datapoints = [
                0, 20, 20, 60, 60, 120, 140, 180, 120, 125, 105, 110, 170,
            ];
            const data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Learning Time",
                        data: datapoints,
                        // borderColor: red,
                        fill: false,
                        cubicInterpolationMode: "monotone",
                        tension: 0.4,
                    },
                ],
            };

            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "line",
                data: data,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,

                    maintainAspectRatio: true,

                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: false,
                            text: "Total Time: 5h 45m",
                        },
                    },
                    interaction: {
                        intersect: false,
                    },
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            display: true,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                            },
                        },
                        y: {
                            display: true,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: "Hours",
                            },
                            suggestedMin: 0,
                            suggestedMax: 200,
                        },
                    },
                },
            });
        </script>
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. I want to make it so that I can **track the user's *totallearningtime* throughout the week and reset it at the beginning of the next week**

Comment: I can offer money to whoever helps me solve this problem as I have a deadline tomorrow. If you give answer please put Paypal or cashapp and I can send $10 from our project budget. Thank you community.

Comment: no need to offer any money, can you please tell me where are you facing the problem? I mean in the django orm or at chart.js?

Comment: I think the problem is more of a django thing because I am rendering out the graph.js with placeholder value but I am not sure how to store data in the django backend

Comment: Because I need to collect the totallearningtime every day Monday-Sunday and render it out on a graph. Can you please help @DivyaPrakash

Comment: are you storing multiple entries in the model with their created timestamps or sometimes by which we can track when the entry was made into the model?

Comment: I am not sure as I have not started storing the data in the model yet. @DivyaPrakash